# Why do I receive a name error? 'AuthorAdmin not defined

Tags: django

Here is the code detail.

admin.py

```
from .models import Author, Genre, Book, BookInstance

@admin.register (Author, AuthorAdmin)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

models.py
The neccesary imports have done. I have been trying to figure out why i recieve the error that AuthorAdmin has not be defined

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', args = [str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Why do you have `AuthorAdmin` in your decarator...? Instead of just `@admin.register(Author)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the decorator

```
@admin.register (Author)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

And

```
admin.site.register (Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

Should work,

Comment: Not using a decorator did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried using ```admin.site.register``` too

Comment: It's clearly mentioned in the doc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects